# Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 usb live section

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, live-usb

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 ISO image from the official website. Then I created a bootable USB using Rufus in Windows 8 (as per the guide). Firstly I want to Try Ubuntu (like from a live CD). I changed first boot device to USB and booted the iso. I got to this window:

[image]

And I don't know what the next step is. I am new to Ubuntu, any help?

Comment: Do you want to install ubuntu or ubuntu server? Because this seems you have downloaded the ubuntu server ISO

Comment: @Cyber_Star , please give the official link to ubuntu 16.04 (not server)

Answer (score 0):

This image will install Ubuntu Server.

If you wish to install it, go ahead and select Install Ubuntu Server and follow the instructions.

You can go to custom installation and do a custom install selecting the correct disk and partitions.

Comment: I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 (not server !! ??) . Can you give the link to 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded the image for [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/server). This is catered more for servers (running with no screen, running networked services etc)

You can download the Ubuntu desktop image from [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and use that. Instructions for installation are available [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) (after [these](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) on creating the disc but you appear fine with that).

Alternatively (may not be the best idea) you can install the server optimised system and then install desktop features with the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage (you can do others desktops*)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

However the server features could cause issues for a new user (particularly if running a non-GUI (text interface) install), in which case you will be better off downloading the desktop ISO

*Ubuntu and other Linux distros can use a variety of desktops, you can find ones that work with Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/178596). Currently the default is Unity, with future releases likely to use Gnome Shell (more on that [here](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence)).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to install ubuntu not ubuntu server you can download it [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=BE&version=16.04.2&architecture=amd64)